# How does Windows's hiding drive mechanism work

Tags: windows, algorithm, registry, pseudocode

There is a interesting way to hide drives in Windows by changing a value in registry. Every drive label corresponds to a value, so that they form a unique value at the end. But how does Windows know what does the value represent?
The mechanism works like this:

```
A: = 2^(0) = 1
B: = 2^(1) = 2
C: = 2^(2) = 4
D: = 2^(3) = 8
…
Z: = 2^(25) = 33554432
```

If you want to hide C: and D:, just type 12 and the system will know you want to hide C: and D:, but can someone write a pseudo code to show it's working principle? I know there must be a much cleverer way to do besides using so many cases or if then else clause…

Comment: drivestohide = drivestohide | (1 << drivenumber);

Comment: `if ((drivestohide & (1 << drivenumber)) != 0) then hide-this-drive;`

Comment: Why drivestohide is a boolean? Shouldn't it be a char?